# UIInterfaceOrientation for current device not working

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I want to know current orientation of my device.

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {

    }
```

But this doent work

Comment: You should probably compare to `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait` since you are looking at the _device_ orientation and not the _interface_ orientation. That being said, looking at the docs you will see that `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait`. So this won't change anything, just makes it clearer.

Comment: Despite the docs saying beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications must be called, I find that [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] returns non-zero.  Don't know why.  Maybe because I'm doing startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler: (anybody know why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it,

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation )) {

}
```

this work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable notifications of the device orientation like this :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]
```

then you can query the current orientation

**EDIT :**

From the docs : "The value of this property always returns 0 unless orientation notifications have been enabled by calling `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`" (where 0 is `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`)

Comment: No need of begin generating notifications, just override the `-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` and/or `-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` methods

Answer (score 0):

The

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

will return one of

```
UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

constants. If you just want to check if its 'vertical' or 'horizontal', no matter if upside down or left-right, just check:

`if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {...}`

If you want to detect orientation changes, override the

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {}
```

or

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {...}
```

methods.

Does this help you?

Comment: It could also return `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`, `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist didn't know, thanks! And I never needed to enable notifications to get those methods called (in fact, i am testing it right now)

Comment: but that was not asked by the questioneer

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned in the accepted answer worked for me.

Though my stmt 1 didnt get executed with the below logic

```
myOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if(myOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
    (myOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    // stmt 1;
}
```

this one works for me right

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation )) 
{
    // stmt 1;
}
```